# Correct way to use UNION ALL or DISTINCT or NOT IN

Tags: mysql, distinct, union

I guess I am not using the best approach here. My objective is to get the unique records from two separate tables i.e. 
    table2016 and table2015

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode) FROM table2016 WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/12/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode) FROM table2015 WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
```

This is what I get:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode)
========================
EDM305,EDU313,EDU498
EDM305,EDU313,EDU497
```

I still have repeated records.

Alternatively, I tried the NOT IN option, to no avail - ofcourse I know am close

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode) FROM table2016 WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/12/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
NOT IN
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode) FROM table2015 WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39)
```

I could use some guides.

Comment: `EDM305,EDU313,EDU498` is not same as `EDM305,EDU313,EDU497`

Comment: those records are not repeated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use subquery to combine rows from two tables and then concatenate them:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode)
FROM (
    SELECT coursecode FROM table2016
    WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/12/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
    UNION 
    SELECT coursecode FROM table2015 
    WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
   ) s
WHERE coursecode NOT IN (SELECT coursecode 
                         FROM table2017
                         WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/155' 
                           AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40);
```

Comment: What of if I want to add a condition (exception) to the solution above like, if the student passes a failed course in `table2017` and the pass score is `WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Extend union part: `UNION SELECT coursecode FROM table2017 WHERE score >= 40`

Comment: Yes, I understand this perfectly. I mean, I don't want the passed `coursecode` i.e. EDU498 to be displayed among the printed result? For example, I want to say **Do not print `WHERE score >= 40`** something like that...

Comment: I am not too familiar on how to use the **db fiddle, I am struggling with it (lol)**. But what I desire to achieve is this `WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) >= 40 NOT IN the two(2) SELECTED UNION tables above` and I don't want the final result to have the `coursecode` with the >= 40 printed. I don't know if it makes more sense this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
select DISTINCT(subTable.column)
form (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode) FROM table2016 WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/12/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39

    UNION DISTINCT

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coursecode) FROM table2015 WHERE regno = 'ABC/XY/DEF/155' AND (ca_score + exam_score) <= 39
) as subTable
```